# Intel Compute Stick with Celeron J4125 - no wifi shown

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel, computestick

I purchased on Amazon Intel Compute Stick with Celeron J4125 ( [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BP9BS81D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BP9BS81D) ), with Windows 11 Pro. Wi-Fi was working fine, until I installed Ubuntu 22.10. I downloaded the guide from the store page on amazon ( https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41jRKUiUiTL.pdf ) and downloaded the Wi-Fi for Linux, and reading through their documentation it says that all I really need is to run install.sh, but when I try to run it, I enter my SU for "make clean" and "make driver" and then Terminal just closes. I also found this link ( https://github.com/johnko/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64-intel-compute-stick ), but it's for super old generation of Ubuntu so I don't know if the drivers are compatible

Can someone please help me out with this? If you could just guide me through the process, I already have Ubuntu installed, I'm just trying to figure out how to get Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Audio enabled again. Big thank you .PS this is my first install of Linux, so if there are any technicalities, please explain like I'm 5. Thank you

Comment: From your question. downloaded the Wi-Fi for Linux, Does it say on that site what version of Linux? They are not all the same. From your Github reference it may be this device is quite old and does not work with any current Ubuntu version.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.